# Python inserting variable string as file name

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a file with a unique file name for every time my script runs. I am only intending to do this to every week or month. so I chose to use the date for the file name.

```
f = open('%s.csv', 'wb') %name
```

is where I'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\workspace\new3\stjohnsinvoices\BabblevoiceInvoiceswpath.py", line 143,      in <module>
f = open('%s.csv', 'ab') %name
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'file' and 'str'
```

it works if I use a static filename, is there an issue with the open function, that means you can't pass a string like this?

name is a string and has values such as :

```
31/1/2013BVI
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to put `% name` straight after the string:

```
f = open('%s.csv' % name, 'wb')
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because you are trying to `%` a file, which isn't string formatting, and is also invalid.

Answer (score 7):

you can do something like

```
filename = "%s.csv" % name
f = open(filename , 'wb')
```

or `f = open('%s.csv' % name, 'wb')`

Answer (score 7):

Very similar to peixe.
You don't have to mention the number if the variables you add as parameters are in order of appearance

```
f = open('{}.csv'.format(name), 'wb')
```

Another option - the f-string formatting ([ref](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/f-string-formatting-in-python)):

```
f = open(f"{name}.csv", 'wb')
```

Answer (score 5):

And with the new string formatting method...

```
f = open('{0}.csv'.format(name), 'wb')
```

Answer (score 5):

Even better are f-strings in python 3!

```py
f = open(f'{name}.csv', 'wb')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import hashlib

filename = file_for_download
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read()  # read entire file as bytes
    msg_hash = hashlib.sha256(bytes).hexdigest();
    print(f"MSG_HASH = {msg_hash}")
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: This also does not answer the question.