# how do i open a file in python with variable name?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to open a file that has a random time date stamp as part of its name. Most of the filename is known eg `filename = 2017_01_23_624.txt` is my test name. The date and numbers is the part I am trying to replace with something unknown as it will change.
My question relates to opening an existing file and not creating a new filename. The filenames are created by a separate program and I must be able to open them. I also want to change them once they are open.
I have been trying to construct the filename string as follow but get invalid syntax.

```
filename = "testfile" + %s + ".txt"
print(filename)
fo = open(filename)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python inserting variable string as file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622314/python-inserting-variable-string-as-file-name)

Comment: Not quite. My filename string is more complicated than that one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a file with a partial filename containing a wildcard for it to match. What you would have to do it look at all the files in your directory and pick the one that matches best.

Simple example:

```
import os

filename = "filename2017_" # known section
direc = r"directorypath"

matches = [ fname for fname in os.listdir(direc) if fname.startswith(filename) ]
print(matches)
```

You can however use the `glob` module (Thanks to bzimor) to pattern match your files. See [glob docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html) for more info.

```
import glob, os

# ? - represents any single character in the filename
# * - represents any number of characters in the filename
direc = r"directorypath"
pattern = 'filename2017-??-??-*.txt'
matches = glob.glob(os.path.join(direc, pattern))
print(matches)
```

Similar to first solution is that you still get back a list of filenames to choose from to then open. But with the `glob` module you can more accurately match your files if you so need. It all depends on how tight you want it to be.

Comment: Or easy way is using `glob` with wildcards for filenames. Add this `glob` module version

Comment: Thanks. I thought I might have had to do that but didn't know the directory commands. I almost have it but my output for the filename is as below. it is including square brackets and ' quotes.C:\TEMP\Python>python test.py
['testfile2017_01.txt']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    fo = open(matches)
TypeError: invalid file: ['testfile2017_01.txt']

Comment: @Dindsy `matches` is a list, you will need to choose a filename from it. Also see updated answer. Might find the `glob` module a better choice.

Comment: thanks all. I have 1 solution working. I will look at glob as well. Cheers