# Save filenames as variable's name in Python

Tags: python, json, filenames

I want to save my python to json file, but the thing is, I need to name my json file's name as title's name.

code:

```
data={
    "Title" : title.text,
    "Registration": doctor.text,
    "Keywords": list2,
    "Article": list
}
#title.text="banana"

with open('title.text.json', 'w',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f,ensure_ascii=False)
```

The result I expected:  Save it as banana.json

Edit:
It works with this

```
with open('%s.json' % title_tag.text, 'w',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f,ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: You explicitly opened a file named `data.json`, then wrote to it, why would you expect it to write to `banana.json`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python inserting variable string as file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622314/python-inserting-variable-string-as-file-name)

Comment: @ShadowRanger just edit it.

Comment: @Unni Thank you for the info! It really helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code to achieve this:

```
with open(title.text, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: It's going to save it as html file instead of json file

Comment: you can use string.format to format your string....

 ```with open('{file_name}.html'.format(file_name=title.text), 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f```

In python3.6, you can achieve this by  *with open(f"{title.text}.html", 'w', encoding='UTF'8') as f*

Comment: with open('%s.json' % title_tag.text, 'w',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f,ensure_ascii=False)