# Opening File Using a Variable that Contains File Name Python

Tags: python, file, variables, valueerror, pypdf

Trying to read a pdf file thats name may change, however I have a preliminary script that contains the file name.  So I successfully save that file name to a variable however when I try to open a file using that variable I get an error: "ValueError: embedded null byte"

I have tried a couple solutions for example I attempted using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622314/python-inserting-variable-string-as-file-name),  However I receive the same error.  I have identified a work around using glob, since I can predict the file name (I know there will always be one PDF) however if possible I want to try to avoid using this solution in case in the future we have multiple PDFs to handle.

This is what I have:

```
pdfFileName = pdfFileName[132:220] # File path is correct, I have confirmed
objectPDF = open(pdfFileName,'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(objectPDF)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
print(pageObj.extractText())
```

My Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "verify.py", line 48, in <module>
    objectPDF = open(pdfFileName,'rb')
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

What I would like is for the text of the pdf to be output to the console.  The error is certainly with the way I'm reading the file, if I hard type the file path in it works as expected, but not when a variable is used with the exact same value as the string.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ValueError: embedded null byte  Sorry that was in my question must of accidentally removed when editing.  I'll put it in. @Axium

Comment: You could try using an absolute path, unless it's already like that. @Fletchy1995

Comment: Tried it, did not work :( @Axium

Comment: It seems that the file name has "nulls" in it. This article: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2010/12/24/common-mistakes-as-web-developer/ can help fix it. I'm not posting an answer because I don't know exactly how to fix it.

Comment: You get the error: "ValueError: embedded null byte" because  you attempt to open a filename with nulls in it .

Comment: Also, try using this before `objectPDF = open(pdfFileName,'rb')`: `pdfFileName = pdfFileName.replace('\0','')`. I'm not too sure if it'll work but it's worth a try.

Comment: Actually your comment worked with the replace method.  Thanks @Axium

Comment: I'll put it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this: `pdfFileName = pdfFileName.replace('\0','')` before this: `objectPDF = open(pdfFileName,'rb')`

What that code does is that it removes all "nulls` from the string, which allows everything to run properly.