# Opening a File Inside Nested Folders With Glob In Python

Tags: python, file, directory

I am trying to open a file inside the two folders

```
import glob
import os
wPlayer = '1'
playeritems = 'PlayerFiles/PlayerItems'
with glob.glob(os.path.join(playeritems, open('inventory.%s.txt' % wPlayer, 'r'))) as wPs:
  #do stuff with wPs
```

But it is giving me there error

> There is no such file or directory: 'inventory.1.txt'

But I know for a fact that there is `'inventory.1.txt'` inside PlayerFiles/PlayerItems.

What am I doing wrong? Is it because it is a string?

[I used this question to get where I am now.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622314/python-inserting-variable-string-as-file-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the path and the filename, as constructed with your join, what is `glob` doing there? It looks like you're opening a single file.

```
import os
wPlayer = '1'
playeritems = 'PlayerFiles/PlayerItems'
with open(os.path.join(playeritems,'inventory.%s.txt' % wPlayer), 'r') as wPs:
  #do stuff with wPs
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought I had to find the file first.